# How to set middleware for specific route in Nuxt

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

I am trying to protect api route in my Nuxt.js app using Nuxt auth module. In my nuxt.config.js I have:

```
serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' }
]
```

And I want to use this:

```
router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
}
```

How to add middleware only for specific route which isn't page component?

Answer (score 2):

Thats not the way to protect an API route. I guess you are using an express.js server here.

For example: You have a API endpoint `/getUserData`. With express.js it would look something like this:

```
app.get("/getUserData/:user", ()=> {
   res.json({
      message: "I am a protected API endpoint."
   });
});
```

To protect this endpoint you should create an middleware that checks if the user is allowed to enter this API endpoint or not. Lets create an example. First create an function and lets call it "auth":

```
function auth(req, res, next){
   let user = req.params.user;
   if(user == "admin"){
      next(); //This means to continue its request
   }else {
      res.status(403).json({ message: "Sorry, but you are not allowed }); //Status 403 means forbidden.
   }
}
```

Ok, now we got an very simple authentification middleware we just need to implement it to every API endpoint we need.

```
app.get("/getUserData/:user", auth,  ()=> {
   res.json({
      message: "I am a protected API endpoint."
   });
});
```

I have added the `auth` middleware to this route to protect it.
You can test it now. With `localhost:3000/api/getUserData/admin` you should see the message. If you choose something different then `admin` you will get an error

Comment: At the beginning I was trying to do this in your way, but I had a problem that I couldn't solved. That's why now I try to use nuxt auth middleware module. My problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959450/api-request-authentication-in-nuxt-js-with-auth0-on-client-side

Comment: what problem did you had?

Comment: It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959450/api-request-authentication-in-nuxt-js-with-auth0-on-client-side 
I will be grateful if you take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<script>
export default {
middleware: 'authenticated'
}
</script>
```

in the routes you want to protect

ps: a route is a page component in nuxt

Comment: Thanks, but it works only for page component inside component file. I need to use it for non-component route in global nuxt.config.js as I mentioned - that's the problem